# Checkbox tick displays as dots in Edge browser

Tags: css, checkbox, microsoft-edge

I have a checkbox styled like so:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position:relative;
  top:0.5em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 1.25em;
  width: 1.25em;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input {
  margin:0 0 0.2em 0;
  border-radius:0.1em;
  border:1px solid #d2d2d2;
  padding:0.8em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-size:16px;
  color:black;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before{
  content: "\f00c";
  font-family:"FontAwesome";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1em;
  left: 0.15em;
  top:0.3em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.25em;
  color: #678b4f;
}
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dyc68wpa/2/).

It appears nicely in most browsers and until now, it seems to at least fall back to something useable in more awkward browsers that ignore `-webkit-appearance`.

However, in Edge, the checked version of the checkbox appears as a very small dot (rather than font awesome  tick) that is barely visible. If I remove `-webkit-appearance`, that displays something useable but that then breaks it in the webkit browsers.

Anyone know how I can fix/get around this?

Comment: I don't have Edge here, but can you try forcing the font size (with `!important`). Does that make a difference?

Comment: Thanks for reply @MrLister, but I think I do set the font-size to 16px in `input` css

Comment: It already is showing differently in other browsers! Are you ok with that? If yes, then a little change in properties along with `padding:0` should help here - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/dyc68wpa/3/

Comment: @LukeCaldwell Yes, but who knows what kind of things Edge has in its default stylesheet.

Comment: I have tried the Fiddle in Edge but it appears fine.Adding screenshot below

Comment: Thanks all. I'm ok with it looking different in different browsers. I think complete cross browser look is probably unrealistic without javascript... Would just like it to be useable in all.

Comment: @LukeCaldwell: Did you take a look at the fiddle I linked to in the above comment?

Comment: @LukeCaldwell: And for truly cross-browser -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4sHD3/2/

Comment: @Abhitalks Just curious, but what do the rotations do in the label:after and why are they not all in the same direction?

Comment: Thank you @Abhitalks. Unfortunately I cannot use the second one as I already have form labels that are being actual labels (I can't change them) and the first one seems to have tick outside box in safari.

Comment: @MrLister: It is an old fiddle of mine to demo one of the may ways to stylize checkboxes. It is best when labels are used. The rotation is to rotate a box with two border in "L" formation to look like a check. (This one is doing it without font/images). Thanks for pointing out the direction. The negative ones are typos left behind. :)

Comment: @LukeCaldwell: That's a bummer. I don't have Safari, so couldn't check it.

Comment: @LukeCaldwell But you can have multiple labels per input.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually not a dot, its a super teeny tiny checkbox, because of the padding on the `input`. If you change it from `0.8em` to `0.1em`, you will see what i mean.

Moving the padding from the input element to the `input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before` selector it will work in all browsers the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Edge actually supports `-webkit` properties, but the behavior of `-webkit-appearance` is unexpected (probably a bug). It seems that adding this property allows you to style the checkbox to a certain degree, but the original checkbox is rendered nonetheless. Interestingly despite setting the value to `none` the DOM inspector shows that it remains `checkbox`:

[image]

Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn800749.aspx) says the following about `-webkit-appearance: none`:

> Default. The appearance of an element is **not changed**.

Note that it says "not changed" when you would expect "not rendered". The docs seem to be about IE, so I'm not sure if it's relevant for Edge as well or at all.

One possible workaround is a hack, that only targets Webkit browsers. Add the selector `body:not(*:root)` before the actual selector:

```
body:not(*:root) input[type="checkbox"] {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    @supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  input[type="checkbox"] {
      width:51px;height:51px;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]::-ms-check{
                                color:red;
                                border:0;
                                background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
                            }
}
```

This is for IE `Edge  @supports (-ms-ime-align: auto)`

This is for checkbox when checked  `input[type=checkbox]::-ms-check`